# Possibility of two values in a select list?

Tags: php, javascript, html

is there a way to have two values in a select's option? I have made a redirection script based on the selected item but I would like to submit a value to the next page also.

**Here is the select list**

```
<select size="1" name="Products"
onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) location.href=this.options [this.options.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="">Please Select a Product</option>
<option value="page1.php">Design
Software</option>
<option value="page2.php">Manufacturing
Software</option>
<option value="page3.php">Machine Tools</option>
</select>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't think so :) You should make a function that chose what page to redirect to, depending of real value in your selected option.

Comment: Well this is a good idea! Is there any example?

Comment: Or get a single page redirect that use the value as get parameter `onchange="if(this.options.selectedIndex>0) window.location.href = 'page.php?id='+this.options [this.options.selectedIndex].value"`

Comment: (the second solution is waaaay better, in the first case you'd need to get a js array with relation between id and page, or handle a standard filenaming that includes your value, it'd be ugly :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try adding the extra variable as a GET variable to the url like so

```
<option value="page1.php?var=val">Design</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pick the value and also the content of the li, both can be different;

or, maybe have a separator (some character) in the value attribute and have two values there?